# Adding a new Entry to a Sharepoint 2007 List (Being Pulled with Web Services)

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint-2007

I'm using this code to pass the credentials to the Sharepoint site Web Services,

```
var client = new SiteWebReference.Lists();
System.Net.NetworkCredential passCredentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
client.Credentials = passCredentials;
```

I'm using this code to pull the Sharepoints List of Entries,

```
private IEnumerable<TaskEntry> LoadTasks()
{
  var data = GetListItems("Tasks");
  var result = XElement.Parse(data.OuterXml);
  XNamespace z = "#RowsetSchema";
  var taskItems = from r in result.Descendants(z + "row")
                  select new TaskEntry
                            {
                               TaskName = r.Attribute("ows_LinkTitle").Value,
                               DueDate = r.Attribute("ows_DueDate") != null ? r.Attribute("ows_DueDate").Value : string.Empty,
                               AssignedTo = r.Attribute("ows_AssignedTo") != null ? r.Attribute("ows_AssignedTo").Value : string.Empty,
                            };
   return taskItems;
}
```

I've been searching around for information on adding a new entry to an already existing List, meaning I want to add a new entry to the Tasks List. I've came to the conclusion that this should code should work,

```
public void updateListItemsWS()
{
   var client = new SPWebservices.Lists();
   System.Net.NetworkCredential passCredentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
   client.Credentials = passCredentials;


   System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
   System.Xml.XmlElement elBatch = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Batch");

   elBatch.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");
   elBatch.SetAttribute("ListVersion", "1");

   string strBatch =   "<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>" +
                       "<Field Name='ows_Client'>Miami Coalition of Partners</Field>" +
                       "<Field Name='ows_Title'>TestingApplication</Field>" +
                       "<Field Name='ows_Task_x0020_Type'>Support</Field>" +
                       "<Field Name='ows_Priority'>1</Field>" +
                       "<Field Name='ows_Status'>Assigned</Field>" +
                       "<Field Name='ows_AssignedTo'>57;#Sandro Perez</Field>" +
                       "<Field Name='ows_Owner'>57;#Sandro Perez</Field>" +
                       "<Field Name='ows_Body'>Testing my application</Field>" +
                       "<Field Name='ows_DueDate'>2014-04-21 00:00:00</Field>" +
                       "<Field Name='ows_Area'>2014-04-21 00:00:00</Field>" +
                       "<Field Name='ows_Group_x0020_Task'>WELS</Field>" +
                       "</Method>";

    elBatch.InnerXml = strBatch;

    client.UpdateListItems("Tasks", elBatch);
}
```

But when I check the Sharepoint site the 'new entry' in not present, any suggestions?

This is not the full XML, this is a small piece,

```
    <listitems
xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882"
xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"
xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset"
xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
<rs:data ItemCount="691">
    <z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_ID="2108" ows_Task_x0020_Type="Issue" ows_Client="City University of New York" />
    </rs:data>
```

**Edit:** 
I have made these changes with the help of Vadim,

I now have this code,

```
public class ListsClient : IDisposable
    {
        public ListsClient(Uri webUri, ICredentials credentials)
        {
            _client = new Bluejeanware.MWELS.Lists();
            _client.Credentials = credentials;
            _client.Url = webUri + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
        }

        public ListsClient(Uri webUri)
        {
            _client = new Bluejeanware.MWELS.Lists();
            _client.Url = webUri + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
        }



        public XmlNode CreateListItem(string listName, Dictionary<string, string> propertyValues)
        {
            var payload = new XmlDocument();
            var updates = payload.CreateElement("Batch");
            updates.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");
            var method = payload.CreateElement("Method");
            method.SetAttribute("ID", "1");
            method.SetAttribute("Cmd", "New");
            foreach (var propertyValue in propertyValues)
            {
                var field = payload.CreateElement("Field");
                field.SetAttribute("Name", propertyValue.Key);
                field.InnerText = propertyValue.Value;
                method.AppendChild(field);
            }
            updates.AppendChild(method);
            return _client.UpdateListItems(listName, updates);
        }

        public ICredentials Credentials
        {
            get { return _client.Credentials; }
            set { _client.Credentials = value; }
        }

        public CookieContainer CookieContainer
        {
            get { return _client.CookieContainer; }
            set { _client.CookieContainer = value; }
        }


        public void Dispose()
        {
            _client.Dispose();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected Bluejeanware.MWELS.Lists _client; 
    }
```

Then the CreateTask,

```
public void CreateTask(TaskEntry taskEntry)
    {
        var webUri = new Uri("http://sp.site.com/apps/msite/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx");
        var userName = "username";
        var password = "password";
        var domain = "domain";

        var client = new ListsClient(webUri);
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);

        var taskProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        taskProperties["Client"] = taskEntry.Client;
        taskProperties["Title"] = taskEntry.Title;
        taskProperties["Task_x0020_Type"] = taskEntry.TaskType;
        taskProperties["Priority"] = taskEntry.Priority;
        taskProperties["Status"] = taskEntry.Status;
        taskProperties["AssignedTo"] = taskEntry.AssignedTo;
        taskProperties["Owner"] = taskEntry.Owner;
        taskProperties["Body"] = taskEntry.Body;
        taskProperties["DueDate"] = taskEntry.DueDate;
        taskProperties["Area"] = taskEntry.Area;
        taskProperties["Group_x0020_Task"] = taskEntry.GroupTask;
    }
```

Then I call the CreateTask with a button,

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CreateTask(new TaskEntry
        {
            Client = "VALUE",
            Title = "TestingApplication",
            TaskType = "VALUE",
            Priority = "1",
            Status = "Assigned",
            AssignedTo = "57;#Sandro Perez",
            Owner = "57;#Sandro Perez",
            Body = "Testing my application",
            DueDate = "2014-04-21 00:00:00",
            Area = "VALUE",
            GroupTask = "VALUE",
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put the list id of task list

client.UpdateListItems(strListID, elBatch);

try to use StringBuilder or directly pass value to elBatch.InnerXml="your xml"

Comment: try to use StringBuilder or directly pass value to elBatch.InnerXml="your xml" and then update the item

Answer (score 0):

This occurs since for `Name` attribute  in `Field` element the *field internal name* have to be specified, for example `Title` (not `ows_Title`).

---

You could utilize the following wrapper class that abstracts SharePoint Web Services and make it easier to create list items:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;

namespace App
{
    public class ListsClient : IDisposable
    {
        public ListsClient(Uri webUri, ICredentials credentials)
        {
            _client = new Lists.Lists();
            _client.Credentials = credentials;
            _client.Url = webUri + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
        }

        public ListsClient(Uri webUri)
        {
            _client = new Lists.Lists();
            _client.Url = webUri + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Create a List Item 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="listName">List Name</param>
        /// <param name="propertyValues">List Item properties</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public XmlNode CreateListItem(string listName, Dictionary<string, string> propertyValues)
        {
            var payload = new XmlDocument();
            var updates = payload.CreateElement("Batch");
            updates.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");
            var method = payload.CreateElement("Method");
            method.SetAttribute("ID", "1");
            method.SetAttribute("Cmd", "New");
            foreach (var propertyValue in propertyValues)
            {
                var field = payload.CreateElement("Field");
                field.SetAttribute("Name", propertyValue.Key);
                field.InnerText = propertyValue.Value;
                method.AppendChild(field);
            }
            updates.AppendChild(method);
            return _client.UpdateListItems(listName, updates);
        }

        public ICredentials Credentials
        {
            get { return _client.Credentials; }
            set { _client.Credentials = value; }
        }

        public CookieContainer CookieContainer
        {
            get { return _client.CookieContainer; }
            set { _client.CookieContainer = value; }
        }


        public void Dispose()
        {
            _client.Dispose();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected Lists.Lists _client;  //SharePoint Web Services Lists proxy
    }
}
```

Then you could create a task item as demonstrated below:

```
public void CreateTask(TaskEntry taskEntry)
{
     var webUri = new Uri("http://intranet.contoso.com/");
     var userName = "username";
     var password = "password";
     var domains = "domain";

     var client = new ListsClient(webUri);
     client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);

     var taskProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     taskProperties["Title"] = taskEntry.TaskName;
     taskProperties["DueDate"] = taskEntry.DueDate;
     taskProperties["AssignedTo"] = taskEntry.AssignedTo;
     client.CreateListItem("Tasks", taskProperties);
}
```

Comment: What is the correct way of going about using the CreateTask func

Comment: I was expecting you could replace your method updateListItemsWs with CreateTask

Comment: I did but how would I call it?

Comment: Hmm.. for example like this: CreateTask(new TaskEntry {TaskName="Order approval"});

Comment: It doesn't seem to be creating the new Entry within the List "Tasks"

Comment: It works for me, please make sure web url and credentials are specified properly(webUrl,usename, password and domains variables)

Comment: Everything seems to be in order, I'll edit my post to reflect the changes I've added to my code; see if you find something wrong.